# Работа JS в vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не работает js код, когда пытаюсь собрать его с помощью vue.
Всё отрисовывается корректно, но не запускается скрипт, не меняются выделенные цвета. 
Если что, вот песочница с этим макетом https://codepen.io/Ni55aN/pen/ELGMOy.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>vue-spa</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="traffic-light"></div>
        <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>


<template>
    <div id="traffic-light">
        <div class="light red" :class="{active: current=='red'}"></div>
        <div class="light yellow" :class="{active: current=='yellow'}"></div>
        <div class="light green" :class="{active: current=='green'}"></div>
    </div>
</template>


    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'traffic',
      data () {
          return {
              current: 'red'
          }
        }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    body {
      background: linear-gradient(rgb(52, 166, 255), rgb(71, 124, 255));
      height: 100vh;
    }

    #traffic-light {
      width: 70px;
      height: 240px;
      background: #222;
      border-radius: 8px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    .light {
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 100%;
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
      opacity: 0.2;
      transition: opacity 0.2s
    }

    .active {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .red {
      background: red;
    }
    .yellow {
      background: yellow;
    }
    .green {
      background: green;
    }
    </style>





    import Vue from 'vue'
    import router from './router'
    import traffic from './traffic.vue'
    Vue.config.productionTip = false

    class State {
      constructor(name, dur, next){
        this.name = name;
        this.dur = dur;
        this.next = next;
      }
    }

    class Constroller {
      trigger(state, callback){
        callback(state);
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.trigger(state.next, callback);
        }, state.dur * 1000)
      }
    }


    var app = new Vue({
    el: '#traffic-light', 
      router,
      template: '<traffic/>',
      components: { traffic },
      mounted(){
        var constroller = new Constroller();

        var red = new State('red', 2);
        var yellowR = new State('yellow', 1);
        var yellowG = new State('yellow', 1);
        var green = new State('green', 3);

        red.next = yellowR;
        yellowR.next = green;
        green.next = yellowG;
        yellowG.next = red;

        constroller.trigger(red, (state)=>{
          this.current = state.name;
        });
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

необходимо было class-ы и mounted() перенести из .js файла в .vue файл

traffic.vue

```
 <template>
        <div id="traffic-light">
            <div class="light red" :class="{active: current=='red'}"></div>
            <div class="light yellow" :class="{active: current=='yellow'}"></div>
            <div class="light green" :class="{active: current=='green'}"></div>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
        class State {
          constructor(name, dur, next){
            this.name = name;
            this.dur = dur;
            this.next = next;
          }
        }
    
        class Constroller {
          trigger(state, callback){
            callback(state);
            setTimeout(()=>{
              this.trigger(state.next, callback);
            }, state.dur * 1000)
          }
        }
        
        export default {
            name: 'traffic',
            data () {
              return {
                  current: 'red'
              }
            },
    
            mounted(){
            var constroller = new Constroller();
    
            var red = new State('red', 2);
            var yellowR = new State('yellow', 1);
            var yellowG = new State('yellow', 1);
            var green = new State('green', 3);
    
            red.next = yellowR;
            yellowR.next = green;
            green.next = yellowG;
            yellowG.next = red;
    
            constroller.trigger(red, (state)=>{
              this.current = state.name;
            });
          }
    
            
        }
    
        </script>
    
        <style>
        /* body {
          
        } */
    
        #traffic-light {
          width: 100px;
          height: 350px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          border-radius: 8px;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 15px;
        }
    
        .light {
          display: inline-block;
          border-radius: 100%;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          margin-bottom: 8px;
          opacity: 0.2;
          transition: opacity 0.2s
        }
    
        .active {
          opacity: 1;
        }
    
        .red {
          background: red;
        }
        .yellow {
          background: yellow;
        }
        .green {
          background: green;
        }
        </style>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import traffic from './traffic.vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#traffic-light', 
    template: '<traffic/>',
    components: { traffic },
    
})
```